# Universal Link does not work in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, google-signin, ios-universal-links

I have implemented google sign-in in my app. The problem is when I go to Safari for the sign in I want the user to be redirected back to my app.

The first approach that I tried was using Custom URL scheme. This worked, however the user was shown a pop-up saying 'Do you want to open `(app name)`'.

It appears the solution to this pop-up is Universal Links, which I have implemented. I can seamlessly now navigate to my app from Notes and other apps. However, when I tried this inside my app, it doesn't work and the user is redirected to the website instead of the app.

For testing, I created a website and added a button to it, which was linked to my original website. When I open that website in Safari and click the button, my app opens. So why doesn't the redirection from google sign-in to my website open my app?

Comment: Why not just use https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/ ?

Comment: @GuyLowe : Thanks, that what I am trying now. The current implementation just used a URL that opened in Safari. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal Links *do not* work with automatic redirects. They must be triggered via some sort of user action. The link URL also needs to be on a different domain/subdomain from the page where the link is being clicked (e.g., `example.dom` and `link.example.com`).

Based on your description of link behavior from Notes and other apps, it appears your configuration is correct and you are simply attempting to do something that Universal Links does not support.

For others who find this question via Google and do not have links from Notes working correctly, try the [Universal Links validator tool](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) from [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team).

Comment: Oh no, so how do I achieve this then ? I see a lot of apps return from Safari without the pop-up. How do they do that ?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to accomplish it. Could you share an example of an app that redirects from Safari with no pop up?

Comment: Tinder, BookMyShow, Box8. Anyway, what I found is if I use Google SDK for Sign-In it will directly return to the app after login. The current implementation uses a URL to sign-in which I open in Safari. Looks like using Google SDK is the only solution.

Comment: These apps aren't using *Safari* itself — they're using `SFSafariViewController`. Since the user never leaves the origin app, you're not 'redirecting back'...you're just dismissing the view controller.

Comment: Thanks, I will try using this.

Comment: The subdomain point saved my sanity when debugging this at midnight with bloodshot eyes. If you are using Route53 on AWS you can just set up a vanity subdomain and point it to the same EB instance / Load Balancer