# Facebook apprequest opening app from mobile website

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I have an iphone app that can successfully send Facebook apprequests to other FB users. When a FB user clicks the apprequest notification in the FB mobile iphone app it does the expected behavior. If the user already has the app installed, it immediately opens the app. If the app is not installed, it redirects the user to the app store.

However, if a FB users is viewing the mobile webpage (m.facebook.com) from their iphone and clicks the notification, it will always redirect them to the app store, regardless of if the app is installed or not installed. How can I get the behavior to be the same as the FB app (open the app if installed, open the app store if not installed)?

I've tried different Mobile Web URLs in the FB app settings, but this seems to have no effect.

Comment: Be sure to [file it as a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 5/25/2012, this is a known bug and there is no workaround. The problem is that from the browser, they are unable to tell whether app is installed, so they always redirect to the app store. Confirmed by FB employee.

Comment: Someone (internally, though probably not your source) was looking at this recently and that's the same conclusion we reached; There's no way in the mobile browser to detect the presence of a URL handler for that specific app, so the app store is the only useful place the user can be sent

Comment: do you have source stating its a known issue?

Comment: Well, i'm stating it now, but i'm not sure there's a task in the bug tracker because i think it's simply a limitation of how the system works

Answer (score 0):

You can setup you mobile web url page so it does the smart timer appstore/app redirect. Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109200/383839
This works fine when you run it on m.facebook.com from mobile Safari. But the Facebook app browser fails on this because it tries to open the fb123456789:// scheme even when it doesn't exist - it cannot detect registered url schemes on the device due to ios restrictions. So you have the option to detect the Facebook browser and always show the appstore link instead of running the redirect javascript when the mobile web url is visited from the Facebook app.

Comment: Does the mobile URL even get used when on an iphone? I have the mobile web URL for my app set to www.google.com but when I click a notification in m.facebook.com on my iphone, it still takes me directly to the appstore. However, if I go to m.facebook.com on my computer and click the notification, it does takes me to google.

Comment: Yes, it's getting used. Well, the case I'm describing is using the Facebook app. Browser in the Facebook app doesn't act like m.facebook.com open in Safari. If you try to redirect to the app scheme fb132456789:// in the Facebook app and don't have the app installed on the device it'll just say page not found and at that point you can't do anything.