# redirect from email to mobile browser and then to the app

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, browser, safari

I was wondering if anyone knew if its possible to build a service that sends email to the users, with a link that if they have the app installed it takes them to the app passing through the browser, and if not, then to the appstore, again through the browser? i am concerned that next time the user will go to the mobile browser (safari), since the page refreshes, he will be directed to my app or app store again since that was the last visited page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a similar question here on SO that has a few solutions, [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200)

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is not what I am looking for - I dont want to have anything on the mobile safari, no UI, and no input from the user. Just a blank page that will redirect the user to either the app or the app store. makes sense? thanks.