# ios 6 opening app directly from mail as youtube links

Tags: ios, email, youtube

Even though the YouTube app is now not a built-in app by Apple, it looks like when tapping a youtube link (in mail, for example), which starts with http://www.youtube.com, opens the YouTube app right away.

Is there a way to this for custom apps in iOS 6? I only know of custom schemes as the way to launch an app via URL.

The best solution i came across is in this post = >

[Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200)

But this is not as good as youtube integration. Requires user interaction via a confirm dialog etc. I wonder if IOS treats youtube links special and custom apps won't be able to use it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is build into iOS 6 itself. And it's not possible to register a real domain on a device.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about iOS6, then I think this answers your question:
 [Promoting Apps with Smart App Banners](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)