# .NET Maui, iOS deep-linking how to open Apple Store

Tags: ios, maui, deep-linking

I implemented deep-link for my .NET Maui project for iOS. I followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnqRuiamvjM&ab_channel=XamarinGuy

What I don't know however, if my application is not installed yet, the hyperlink opens the website. However I would like to open Apple Store - directly my application, so user can install my application.

Any idea what should I change?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions must directly contain all relevant code. **Add to question** that code. Its good to provide a link for context, but the question must "stand on its own".

Comment: The code can be found in the video or from the link:
https://xamaringuyshow.com/dotnet-maui-ios-applinking/

Comment: That is NOT “adding relevant code to question “. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: *also copy the relevant code into the question*. That is, if all links were broken/missing, the question should still contain all the info needed to answer it.

Comment: I just expected that somebody knows how to adjust the Maui project or probably adjust something in App Store or webpage so it will be able to redirect the App Store in case the application is not installed.  Sure I understand it good to have a code example shown here. However in order to enable deep-link support, especially for iOS it is necessary to change so many things and not only in project but also on a website so it is much easier to watch the video than put the code here. Moreover the tutorial author put the source code there as well.

Comment: google knows how. Searching `ios deep link go to app store` finds https://stackoverflow.com/a/54352873/199364: *"when there's no installed app able to respond to a specific https domain link, the system will simply open it on a web browser. Consequently, you cannot force iOS to open such links on AppStore directly. What you can do is to check whether the running device is iOS when your website gets accessed and ask the system to show your app on AppStore."* That is, if client is iOS, your website should `redirect` to app store specifying your app.

Comment: Thank you @ToolmakerSteve! I also asked Google but I put "maui" into the question which did not give me to the correct answer :-)

Comment: ahh, interesting. I would have put "maui ios", or "xamarin ios" if that didn't find a good answer. In this case I knew the website was involved, so left it out.