# Custom URL opening my application on iPhone - like it's done with Youtube

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, url-scheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like)

I know I can create a custom URL scheme and launch my application with it. So I can catch the URL like that:

```
myapp://image/1
```

and open myapp showing the user image ID=1.

But as far as I'm concerned - the YouTube app behaved a bit different, using an url like this:

```
http://youtube.com/v/<ID>
```

the iPhone would catch the `http` scheme but starting with youtube address and open YT app.

Is something like this possible with my own app, or is it some private api thing? Can I, somehow, make my app launch on the open of URL:

```
http://app.myapp.com/image/1
```

or is it not possible at all?

Comment: Here is a question where the answers outline possible ways of doing this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/ Let me know how it goes! I may need to do something similar in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

http/https/ftp scheme name is for web pages which is opened by Safari. I know these exceptions

- Web links that point to http://maps.google.com are redirected to the Maps app.
- Web links that point to http://www.youtube.com are redirected to the YouTube app.
- iTunes store links (http://phobos.apple.com/etc..) are sent to the iTunes (or App store) app.

I dont think you can do something like http://app.myapp.com/image/1 to redirect to your app.

Here is Apple [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007895-SW1) for Youtube URL scheme.