# Displaying Smart Banner in iOS 6 UIWebview component

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, ios6

I would like to use a Smart Banner on my website. It works great in Safari mobile but is not displayed at all in Tweetbot, Twitter App, Facebook App, or any other application that will display my website in a UIWebView component.

Do you know a way to achieve that or a workaround that will let me detect whether my application is already installed and display a message only if it is not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like might hold some hints

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I think in #ios6, the cookies are sandboxed per application so we can't hack this way anymore.

Comment: Beyond that, the `window.location="x-my-app://blah"` with a "still there?" timeout is a good way to go but it will redirect to your app instead of just detecting whether it is installed or not.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I think SmartBanners only work in MobileSafari.  However, you can design your own SmartBanner interface and use the technique outlined in this question: [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like) to do that.

Comment: Sorry but @Nevir already provide this link in its comment, see my answer in the comment thread of the question. Thanks for the proposal anyway.