# Mobile Safari Page unload/hide/blur for Deep Linking

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari, deep-linking

I am looking for an event on mobile safari that will detect when the page has been hidden due to a redirect. I want to open my app directly if a user has it installed, then attempt facebook if it is installed, and if not then go to the webpage for that id.

1. If 'myapp' is installed, then myapp is opened. But the safari tab still gets redirected to facebook.com
2. If 'myapp' is not installed, but facebook is, then facebook ios app is opened. But the safari tab still gets redirected to facebook.com

I've created a [test link](http://www.codenothing.com/dev/stackoverflow/deep-link/) with the following HTML/JS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>Redirect Test</title>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <button>Open Oreo</button>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function(){
            jQuery( 'button' ).on( 'click', function(){
                    var myid = null, fbid = null;

                    // Watch for page leave to kill timers
                    jQuery( window ).on( 'pagehide pageshow blur unload', function(){
                            if ( myid ) {
                                    clearTimeout( myid );
                            }
                            if ( fbid ) {
                                    clearTimeout( fbid );
                            }
                    });

                    window.location = "myapp://fbprofile/oreo";
                    var myid = setTimeout(function(){

                            // My app doesn't exist on device, open facebook
                            window.location = "fb://profile/oreo";
                            fbid = setTimeout(function(){

                                    // Facebook doesn't exist on device, open facebook mobile
                                    window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/oreo";
                            }, 100);
                    }, 100);
            });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nice code.
**EDIT:** (removed suggestion about adding `return false;`)

Try setting a check within your `setTimeout` functions in stead of just clearing the Timeouts. (I find that clearing is much more effective for intervals in stead of simple 1-time setTimeout calls). Also, I would check to make sure the user isn't on a desktop browser before trying a native app protocol like my `app://` or `fb://` as those browsers will try to follow that location and end up displaying an error.

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirect Test</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0' />
</head>
<body>
<button>Open Oreo</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var mobileExp = /android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile|o2|opera mini|palm( os)?|plucker|pocket|pre\/|psp|smartphone|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce; (iemobile|ppc)|xiino/i;

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery( 'button' ).on( 'click', function(){

        // Don't give desktop browsers a chance to fail on a nativeapp:// protocol
        if(!mobileExp.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/oreo";
            return;
        }

        var clicked = +new Date, timeout = 100;

        window.location = "myapp://fbprofile/oreo";

        setTimeout(function(){
            // If we're still here after a (timeout), try native facebook app
            if (+new Date - clicked < timeout*2){
                console.log('clicked '+ (+new Date - clicked) +' ago- go to FB');
                window.location = "fb://profile/oreo";
            } else {
                console.log('too late for facebook');
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                // If we're still here after another (timeout), try facebook web app
                if (+new Date - clicked < timeout*2){
                    console.log('clicked '+ (+new Date - clicked) +' ago- go to browser');
                    window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/oreo";
                } else {
                    console.log('too late for browser');
                }
            }, timeout);
        }, timeout);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, un-comment the console logs and do some experimenting with the value of `timeout`. This exact code tested successfully in IOS 6.1 Safari and Safari 6.0.2 Mac. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately this doesn't apply because I am using a button and redirecting with javascript, rather then a link. So there is no 'link click bubble' event to cancel out.

Comment: You are correct - I shot from the hip and missed that fact entirely! The suggestion about browser check stands, though. See my edited answer above - moved the relevant checks within the `setTimeout` functions and got rid of the `clearTimeout`s.

Comment: Safari reopens last visited page once restarted and the script won't work in this case. In order to avoid this behaviour, you can append `window.close();` to the `else` blocks.

Comment: solution for Safari on iOS 13.3 which does not use `Date`: https://gist.github.com/diachedelic/0d60233dab3dcae3215da8a4dfdcd434