# Getting insecure content when using redirects in webview below android 4.4

Tags: android, webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

We have an application where we are doing some redirects using **iFrames** in a webview. This redirects happens on a HTTPS page with a custom protocol (example: customProtocol://)

This redirects are then intercepted in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to execute our logic.

The redirects works in kitkat and above which has chromium based webviews but on phones/tablets that are below android 4.4 we get **The page at displayed insecure content from ** error and it gets blocked and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not called.

Is there any way to allow webview below 4.4 to allow custom protocols in https pages ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, Give it a try to this

> Link directly to custom protocol handlers for mobile

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>App Redirection</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- iframe used for attempting to load a custom protocol -->
<iframe style="display:none" height="0" width="0" id="loader"></iframe>

<script>(function(){
// For desktop browser, remember to pass though any metadata on the link for deep linking
var fallbackLink = 'http://example.com/my-web-app/'+window.location.search+window.location.hash;
// Simple device detection
var isiOS = navigator.userAgent.match('iPad') || navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone') || navigator.userAgent.match('iPod'),
isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match('Android');
// Mobile
if (isiOS || isAndroid) {
// Load our custom protocol in the iframe, for Chrome and Opera this burys the error dialog (which is actually HTML)
// for iOS we will get a popup error if this protocol is not supported, but it won't block javascript
document.getElementById('loader').src = 'custom-protocol://my-app'+window.location.search+window.location.hash;
// The fallback link for Android needs to be https:// rather than market:// or the device will try to
// load both URLs and only the last one will win. (Especially FireFox, where an "Are You Sure" dialog will appear)
// on iOS we can link directly to the App Store as our app switch will fire prior to the switch
// If you have a mobile web app, your fallback could be that instead.
fallbackLink = isAndroid ? 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.myapp' :
'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/my-app/idxxxxxxxx?mt=8' ;
}
// Now we just wait for everything to execute, if the user is redirected to your custom app
// the timeout below will never fire, if a custom app is not present (or the user is on the Desktop)
// we will replace the current URL with the fallbackLink (store URL or desktop URL as appropriate)
window.setTimeout(function (){ window.location.replace(fallbackLink); }, 1);
/*
Q&A
I have a native desktop app as well, how do I link to a custom protocol handler on the desktop?
IE Only: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx#Version_Vectors
All Other Browsers: Use a custom plugin like iTunes does: http://ax.itunes.apple.com/detection/itmsCheck.js
*/
})();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ref:
 [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/pulletsforever/2662899) by  pulletsforever

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715535/mobile-safari-page-unload-hide-blur-for-deep-linking/14751543#14751543) Link