# Layar: Opening App Store from Layar HTML Widget in JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, app-store, layar

I'm unsing a HTML widget in Layar which has to control all the interaction. So no Layar buttons. I trying to use a simple JavaScript / JQuery function to open a target app in the App Store:

```
$('.btn-download').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "itms://itunes.com/apps/someApp";
});
```

I do something simular opening a mail window with mailto: which works fine. Somehow this will do nothing.
B.t.w. It only has to work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "http://itunes.com/apps/someApp";
}, 25);

window.location = "custom-uri://";
```

Copied this from: [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200)

Comment: I tried the http roundtrip, also doesn't work, I'm afraid. The rest of the work-around you suggested also didn't do the trick. Thanks anyway.