# Open iOS application from email link

Tags: c#, ios, .net

My ios application has using a custom url scheme. I want to open application from link in email. But, i want to send one link for all platforms (desktop/mobile). If user clicks the link from his ios device, i want to detect it and open my application. If application is not installed in ios device, again i want to detect it and redirect the user to app store. But, i also want to open my desktop site when the user clicks the link from desktop.

I need some methodology to detect whether the user installs he application in my server side (which is coded in .net/c# framework), then i need to take some actions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare and share link with http scheme to your server and use user agent to detect platform (PC/iOS) server side. Then follow the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109200/2714032