# Detect if app is installed on iOS device and display appropriate message

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone

I want users who access my website via their iOS device an html page that displays a message:
"App is installed" if a specific app is installed (not any app - but a specific app I'm working on) and "App is not installed" if it is not installed.

I don't want to launch the app - just show the right message.

Comment: And where do you plan to show this message? On the HOME-SCREEN?

Comment: nope - on the html page.

Comment: And how do you access this page?

Comment: Are you trying to show a install app Link where you want to do this? Then Sorry but HTML page wont have access to the system files and binaries. This is done by the Play Store or the App Store

Comment: apple smart app banner does that, if the app is installed it shows an "Open" button, and if it isn't installed it shows an "View" that links to the app store

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this result directly, but there are work arounds that might prove effective: [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200)