# Link to open up iOS app from facebook and twitter page and other ios app?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

Hi I have a requirement in my app. From my ios Application(myapp),i share a link to facebook. Then I opened up my facebook account in browser or Facebook application and clicked the link, link should open in  myapp if myapp is installed in the device otherwise link should open in browser. How can I achieve this ? Please suggest me step by step. Thanks in advance for your consideration and help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible. I have looked at various questions including
[Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200)

as I am sure you might have already done but these questions target their own app, mainly web app, but you want that behavior to occur from an app that is not yours like twitter or facebook. But what you can do is show them two links on facebook/twitter, if they have installed press link 1 and if they want to install, press link 2 and you can pass parameters in link 1 as you might already know.
I will also keep checking answer of this question if some one comes and gives a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called custom URL scheme in iOS. It will help you to create a URL scheme which identifies your application. You can post link with this URL scheme and when you tap on this link on your iOS device it will open up your mobile app. Please see the link below to know how to setup this.

[Custom URL Scheme in iOS](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is called 'deep URL linking'. Facebook have built a service called 'App Links', which seems pretty cool.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links