# How to relate marketing campaign ad with iOS app install

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, web

I was always interested in how clicking on particular ad, downloading and installing app can be related to the same click-on-ad action. Yes, there is advertising identifier which is unique per device and it's clear how it works when user clicks ad within AppA (from ServiceA), and then downloads AppB which has embedded SDK from the same ServiceA.

BUT how it works when user clicks ad on mobile website? I haven't found a solution how to retrieve advertising identifier through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer but a thread discussing something similar which i believe my lead to your solution - hope it is helpful:

[Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200)