# How to redirect to ios settings in Safari use javascript in ios9

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, ios9

I want to know how to redirect to the iOS settings from Safari.

I've seen this on one website: I opened this website in Safari, and there is a button, and when I click this button, it can redirect to the iOS settings.

I think this can be realized by javascript.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Note: I am using iOS9.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks,my english is not good enough

Comment: If the website can do it, why not just look at the source to see how it works?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I've seen the source,unfortunately I didn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry,I have to answer my own question.I've found the solution.Just tested in ios9

This is my code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="redirect()" value="Redirect">
<script>
    var redirect = function() {
        window.location.href = "prefs:root=Settings";
    }
</script>
```

When I open this page in Safari and click the button,it can redirect to the `Settings`

If I want to redirect to `Settings->General`,it should be:

```
window.location.href = "prefs:root=General";
```

If I want to redirect to the `Settings->General->Profiles`,then should be:

```
window.location.href = "prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList";
```

And I found the Preference list http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences.app

Comment: Good ! only IOS9+ support this ?

Comment: Tested this on iOS 10 and it no longer works. Also tried the new schema `Apps-prefs:`.

Comment: Any solution that works nowadays in the era of iOS13?

Comment: I was able to get it working with iOS13 with `App-prefs://prefs:root=Settings` but couldn't figure out a way to traverse the path or jump into a different preference. Seems like all the browser would allow is redirecting to Settings

Comment: I've tried App-prefs://prefs:root=Settings&path=Bluetooth no doesn't work on iOS 12 either.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar question like this and here is the answer. The only thing you have to change and figure out is the link to the application.

[The SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/2391031#2391031)

Comment: I don't want to open some app,I just want to redirect the ios settings.

Comment: Look at this website and then make the link like you want to have it: [link](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/apple-settings-app)

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen you've answered your question by yourself