# How to open Safari's settings from web page on iOS 9.3+

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, settings

Here I find solution how to open Settings in iOS: [How to redirect to ios settings in Safari use javascript in ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685561/how-to-redirect-to-ios-settings-in-safari-use-javascript-in-ios9)

```
<input type="button" onclick="redirect()" value="Redirect">
<script>
    var redirect = function() {
        window.location.href = "prefs:root=Settings";
    }
</script>
```

But there is some problems with this solution on my iPhone 6s plus 9.3.2(13F69):
- this solution doesn't work on my particelar iPhone, but work on iPhone 6s
- link to `prefs:root=Safari` doesn't work

So I've got 2 questions:

1. How could I find out why this solution doesn't work on my particular phone?
2. How could I open Safari's in Settings app?

Comment: Same problem… found a solution?

Comment: @JBA No :( seems there is no solution

Comment: i have had issues with this as well... i get 'open this page in "settings"?', and then  "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" I've also tried location.href = "App-prefs:root=Settings";

Answer (score 12):

window.location.href = 'App-prefs://prefs:root=Settings';

Try this, Working in iOS 13

Comment: Works on iOS 12! Check here for a list of URIs https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560#user-content-url-schemes

Comment: @Mayur Kanojiya Can you give an example link for the open safari setting from the Website? Because it's opening only setting root while opening url.