# MacOS Safari : programatically open Safari Settings of a Website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, safari, settings

So my web app is trying to request a permission for showing a notification, but what if User clicked "Deny"? It seems pretty easy for chrome/Edge/Firefox, but not for Safari.

I see two ways to handle this.

**On Safari**

I can write all the steps: "Go to Safari Menu > Settings... > Notification > Look for 'my-web-app.com' > From DropDown, Select "Allow"" and I design a good UI for this.

[image]

**On Chrome**

Chrome is cool! It has a url using which one can navigate to site settings.
For example:

```
chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Ftests.peter.sh%2F
```

[image]

Easily, I can provide a hyperlink to the settings page.

I was more interested in knowing, if by chance, there's a similar way to navigate User to settings page for my website.

Comment: I think this should work. Thank you!

Comment: What should work? Did a comment disappear?

Comment: Yes @LucasvanDongen comment was deleted. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502269/1739882

Comment: But does it really work for macOS?