# How to share Deeplinking url via Email

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, uiactivityviewcontroller

I tried to share Url, for instance,deeplink:// via default iphone Email.But unfortunately,the link doesn't turn as hyperlink mode so that it can be clickable and directed to the specified location.So please kindly help me for the below code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"deeplink://"]];

NSArray * activityItems = @[url];
NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeMessage];

UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I just want to make it to hyperlink mode and be able to directed it towards safari browser and to open the app via deeplinking.

Comment: This is because Deep Links not URL links actually. But you can switch to Universal Links if possible.

Comment: can u please help me to do it?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010915/open-app-from-sms-with-my-url-scheme-as-a-link

Comment: i tried it but still the same.Can u please share me the code .

Answer (score 0):

Custom URI schemes are not a valid solution for this. As you discovered, they are not recognized as links in many situations, but there are other more serious issues too. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41129090/5394680) for more information