# Apple rejected my app because tips are not allowed ( they call them Charity donation)

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

Apple rejected for the third time my app.
I add in this app a "donation" process. There are tips were i get a fee on every transaction. The transaction was made via PayPal on a UIWebView ( because PayPal sdk not support credit card on my Country :( )

The response from Apple's review is :

> While donations may not be taken within an app, you may provide a link
>   to your website that launches Safari for users to make a donation. You
>   may also add a link to send an SMS to make the donation.
>
> We are unable to proceed with the review of your app until this issue
>   has been addressed.

How i can made a flow were when i click donate i open safari then i can return back on transaction finished ?

**Edit**

I want to say how return to app without the small link on left corner

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because developer centric questions about application stores are considered off topic here on SO, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/4667835) meta answer by a moderator.

Comment: why ? is a request for developer support ? I want to say how return to app without the small link on left

Comment: Then ask the specific, technical question about how to achieve that and don't ask about how to get your app approved by Apple.

Comment: "How i can made a flow were when i click donate i open safari then i can return back on transaction finished ?" is not "how to get my app approved by apple "

Comment: I think what David means is that change the title of your question to "How I can ...." rather than "Apple rejected my app"

Answer (score 1):

Apple probably don´t want these kind of action because they want you to use their payment rules and they have a fee with 30%.

What you could do is to fire Safari as Apple suggest, make a button and call this function:

```
func openSafari() {
    if let let url = "someURl", let requestUrl = URL(string: url) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(requestUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(requestUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

This will launch Safari with your suggested URL and then you can go  back to the app with the small link that automatically will popup at the top left corner.

Comment: Thanks Rashwan , there is any things to add a callback or listener tu safari web view ? This for make return to app automatic

Comment: Just saw your update on your question, yes there is. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123611/open-an-app-ios-android-via-javascript-with-a-fallback-redirect-to-app-play-s) post of how to do that.

Comment: Can't he use `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: @Hemang, he probably could but I´m not sure how he should close it when the user is done.

Comment: @RashwanL thanks, i need to take a post . Do you know how i can do this with safari ?

Comment: @Qu4sar, what do you mean by "I need to take a post"?

Comment: POST call , how i can pass a body in a request to safari .