# Determine if app is installed, if installed then open link in app else navigate to app store

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, deep-linking

I know this question is asked multiple times on SO. But none of answers worked for me in iOS 12

I know using branch.io, I can do this but I don't want to use any paid service

What I have tried

```
window.location.replace('myapp://');
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.replace('appstorelink://);
}, 1000);
```

But it shows an ugly popup that says `safari can not open this page` if app is not installed. After clicking on `'Ok'` button it redirects to app store

Is there any workaround to stop or avoid the popup?

Comment: Have you tried this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200

Comment: The second solution I have tried, the first solution is not great as it has pitfalls in it........ such as if user have installed app once and uninstalled the app..... and then tries to hit the link

Comment: I am a little concerned about the order on how you change the window location. In the first solution in the link myapp:// URI is given second. Please just cross check it :)

Comment: @Lonewolf that won't cause anything, as I am setting `timer = null` on visibilitychange event