# How to detect and redirect a user to a website's app?

Tags: html, mobile, hyperlink

How can I create a link on a website that links to a page in Uber Eats, but if the user is in a mobile device it either opens the Uber Eats app, or if the user does not have the app downloaded, it prompts them to the app store to download it?

Is this something I do, or is handled on Uber Eats side of things?

Here is a drawing showing my question/issue better...

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like)

Comment: Yes, but was wondering if in the 11 years that has passed since that question was asked, the technology has changed.