# What is the href link to open chat on imo app?

Tags: html, href

I cant seem to find the a tag href example for IMO (free video calls and chat) where user can click the link on the website and open a chat in IMO app. Example `<a href="imo://[CODE]">`

Comment: You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like