# Is it possible to open one app in an android device, from a website?

Tags: android

Will it be possible, if I have a button in a website and and when clicked, it will do a trigger function and a related App will open automatically in an Android device? In iPhone it is getting possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From a previous Stack Overflow Question:

[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Namely:

Use an `<intent-filter>` with a `<data>` element. For example, to handle all links to twitter.com, you'd put this inside your `<activity>` in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="twitter.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, when the user clicks on a link to twitter in the browser, they will be asked what application to use in order to complete the action: the browser or your application.

Of course, if you want to provide tight integration between your website and your app, you can define your own scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, in your web app you can put links like:

```
<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here">
```

Comment: Please note that hackbod presents a decent argument for not doing this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908

Answer (score 0):

It is possible: you need to register a URL handler in your app.

EDIT: see [How to listen for a custom URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471503/how-to-listen-for-a-custom-uri) for details.

Comment: Please note that hackbod presents a decent argument for not doing this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908

Comment: It is a decent argument: I personally like the http argument, as it covers cases where your app isn't installed. Personal choice, though, I have to say.

Comment: I find it annoying to not be able to click market:// links in my main computer's web browser.

Comment: hehehe: someone should release a set of browser plugins to translate market links back into http links.

Comment: A few do exist for chrome. http://www.google.com/search?q=android+market+links+from+chrome

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to launch an Android app from a web browser that's not on the device.

Take a look at Chrome to Phone for an example.

http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/