# In android a custom URI into a EPUB call to an app

Tags: android, uri, protocols, epub

I have a text in EPUB, in this text there's a link that starts "E2L://".When somebody clicks in the link,  I want to open an app that shows the link text. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: If I could register my own protocol (E2L://) in android OS, that would solve the problem, because all app could understand it, couldn't it? is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can do it : You should register in your Manifest file like below :

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="anton" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <--Not positive if this one is needed
...
</intent-filter>
```

For further reference check this [Listen to Custom URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471503/how-to-listen-for-a-custom-uri)
and 
[Start app from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Comment: in the manifest of de app that I want to open with the link (E2L://) in the EPUB?

Comment: Need to specify you schema in my case i gave as anton , in you case give your schema , i think E2L is your Schema

Comment: I think , I've accepted it.. I linked:  Was this post useful to you? "Yes". I tried to vote  you up, but I haven't enough reputation to vote. Is there anything else I can do ?

Comment: I've tried this and it worked! :) but how can I pass and receive parameters? thank you!