# Android: Scanning barcode to start Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

Is it possible to create an qr-barcode, such as, that only by scanning this code (with ZXing Barcodescanner) an Intent will start, that opens my application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have a special type of URL when clicked opens the desired application (See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228)). All you need to do is embed this URL in a QR-code and if the reader is smart enough, it will show the URL which when clicked should open your application.