# Handle a link in the Android browser/webview to start directly an application

Tags: java, android

I want my application to be opened from a link,
by following the directions of [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228).
Well, it works fine (most of the time.... this is the reason I am asking for help).

My html link is

```html
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.mark.MY_ACTION;end">Open Application</a>
```

My intent filter is in the form

```xml
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.mark.MY_ACTION"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE">
</intent-filter>
```

So far so good (I hope). It works fine from m-o-s-t of the browsers.

To test the above I wrote a demo activity

```java
final WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
setContentView(webview); 
webview.loadUrl("http://www.myhomepage.com/");
```

The page `http://www.myhomepage.com/` has some custom links/hrefs (including 
the inent one).

Pressing regular links opens me a browser with those links, but pressing my "special 
link" (the intnet one) opens a 404 page

> Web page not available
>   intent:#Intent;action=com.mark.MY_ACTION;end
>   might be temporarily down....

While Diane mentioned in [The above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228),

> They allow you to direct the launch to only your app without the user having the option of instead going to the browser or any other app.

Comment: I believe here's what you're looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser/2958870#2958870

Comment: This is one approach using scheme, but as Diane (my guru) said 
"We strongly discourage people from using their own schemes, unless they are defining a new world-wide internet scheme."
I want to use intent:....

Answer (score 1):

your Intent Filter is some same as mentioned by Diana

```
<activity android:name=".AntonWorld"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="anton" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So yours should be like:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <data android:scheme="com.mark.MY_ACTION"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Did not test if android.intent.category.VIEW is required. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Diana also says that she had some issue with the order of the subelements. Maybe you need android.intent.category.BROWSEABLE before android.intent.category.Default.

Comment: I don't want my url to be
anton://www.....com,
I want to forward an implict intent to my application.

Comment: it will not be anton now as you have changed the following Intent Filter subelement: 
    <data android:scheme="">

Comment: and your link is 
`code`<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.mark.MY_ACTION;end">Open Application</a>

I think it should be 

<a href="com.mark.MY_ACTION://some_info">Open Application</a>, I will make a test class and check it as well.

Comment: What you are suggesting, is another approach. And it works pretty much the same as the "intent:" approach.
Try using your approach from this browser
http://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/

Answer (score 1):

Try my simple trick:

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("classRegister:")) {                  
                Intent MnRegister = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), register.class); startActivity(MnRegister);
            }               
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

and my html link:

```
<a href="classRegister:true">Go to register.java</a>
```

or you can make < a href="classRegister:**true**" > <- "true" value for class filename

however this script work for mailto link :)

```
        if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
            String[] blah_email = url.split(":");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{blah_email[1]});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, what_ever_you_want_the_subject_to_be)");
            Log.v("NOTICE", "Sending Email to: " + blah_email[1] + " with subject: " + what_ever_you_want_the_subject_to_be);
            startActivity(emailIntent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in `Manifest.xml`

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="www.parag-chauhan.com"
        android:path="/test"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

For test create another project and run below code

```java
Intent i = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://www.parag-chauhan.com/test")
);
startActivity(i);
```

You can also pass parameter in link. For more info, see my blog post [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2013/03/make-link-in-android-browser-start-up.html)