# Open android program when click on url

Tags: android, url

I want to intercept clicking over url. For example: In my GMAIL I have mail with link like this:

```
www.xyz.com/test/
```

How to register my program to be listed in chooser?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid problem :(
After closing manifest file and several refres,clean and rebuild + restart Eclipse -> Problem dissapear.

I had the same problem monts ago. I hope that Eclipse team will fix soon this.