# How to communicate between Android web browser and my custom app

Tags: android

I would like to launch my custom app from web browser. I have found the answer to this question here: [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228)

Now I would like to return some data from my custom application back to the web page that opened it and then POST it to the server.

Any ideas how to do this?

Matra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, sorry.

You are welcome to have your custom application load some other Web page in the browser using an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. Or, you can integrate `WebView` into your application and have much greater control.

Comment: 1) What if I make my local application a "local web server" that listen to requests and send a HTTP request from browser to my app which would then in turn return response to the server? 2) Is it possible that application GUI will pop up over the browser gui when it receives such a request?

Comment: @matra: 1) This could work but is a big-time security hole, because any app on the device can make HTTP requests of your app, as can any app on any other device on the local network segment. 2) No, that would only happen if your Web page had a link that triggered some separate app's UI, not if it loaded a fresh HTML page or used AJAX-style HTTP requests.