# Navigation from HTML5 page to android app

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to navigate from html5 app in web browser to android app installed on phone.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question referred to by user247245 in his comment provides one way of doing.  Another way is to use a Java class together with your HTML5 application to handle the launching of the application activity.

Have a look at this post: http://satishbellapu.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/launching-android-native-application.html - while the author's English is not great, it does explain (more-or-less) how to do this.