# How to start up an Android app via browser link?

Tags: android

I read this 2 year old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app) about how to start an app via a browser link. I follow the instruction from [hackbod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236398/hackbod) to do not use a custom scheme.

I prepare a html-site with the following link:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;package=com.jamic.secapp;end">Sec App</a>
```

The intent-filter part of my manifest.xml looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.jamic.secapp"
...
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="intent"/>
</intent-filter>
...
```

When I open the html site in a browser (I tried the standard android browser and dolphin browser) and click on the link, the browser redirected me to the Play-Store and I get the message:

```
No result found for "pname:com.jamic.secapp"
```

But when I open the html-site with the standard HTML-Viewer from android, the link works fine.

So whats wrong? I don't want to be a bad boy and use custom schemes :P

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: should be `pname://com.jamic.secapp`

Comment: @Shivan: in my html-link or in the response from Play-store?

Comment: I have the same problem, same error and the "pname:xxxx" always refer to my application package name. Have you found a solution for that yet?

Comment: I have removed "package=com.jamic.secapp;" from the uri and it works now. I believe, this problem should has a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to use `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>` instead?

Comment: Also `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>` don't work for me