# Make a link in the Android browser call an intent receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I would like to make a link in Android browser to be able to call a receiver.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228) post on how to make a link start my app and tries to do the same for my startup receiver receiver, but it didn't work. 
Is it possible?

My receiver is configured as follows:

```
        <receiver
        android:name="com.wiziapp.wiziappweb.app.MyStartupIntentReceiver"
        android:label="@string/search" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myapp" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The link I use to test it is:

```
<a href=myapp://enable_notification">Enable notification</a>
```

Comment: @nammari i think, you should not use too much sign to show your feeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to make a link in Android browser to be able to call a receiver.

That is not possible.

> My receiver is configured as follows:

`ACTION_VIEW` is used with `startActivity()`, not `sendBroadcast()`, so your second `<intent-filter>` is unlikely to ever be used.

> The link I use to test it is

Links only call `startActivity()`, not `sendBroadcast()`. Your are welcome to have the link point to a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity that sends the broadcast and then calls `finish()` to go away.