# How to open an installed app from an email URL in Android?

Tags: android, email, url, twitter, html-email

I want to open my app from an email URL, basically like the example shown below for [Twitter.com](https://twitter.com/).

**Email with link:**

[image: Email with link]

**Selection to open app or browser:**

[image: Select app or browser]

**After you click on the app choice, the Twitter app opens:**

[image: Open Twitter app]

I tried the following code, but it is not working:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:host="www.twitter.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

If anyone has a proper answer, please write some examples here.

Comment: change android:host value to your url host path and android:scheme to https from http. should work

Comment: i want to open my app this is just example.@VnyKumar

Comment: @VnyKumar i want to open my app what should i write in manifest file?

Comment: Just go through this [Deeplinking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) google document. You will come to know about this deep linking concept. I hope this will help some body.

Answer (score 16):

The following code worked for me:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

    <data
        android:host="www.my.app.com"
        android:path="launch"
        android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

With the email link set as `http://www.my.app.com/launch`.

Ref: [Launching Android Application from link or email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960248/launching-android-application-from-link-or-email)

Comment: Were you able to configure this within your `config.xml` file, or were you updating `AndroidManifest.xml` directly ?

Comment: Could you explain how to make it accept both http and https?

Comment: @rraallvv, not sure, but did you tried adding another intent filter with `https`?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I was searching for something like a regex pattern, although I'm not sure if that's posible.

Answer (score 5):

Ex: Your url will be something like https://roadies.com and you have the intent filter in manifest as below

```
        android:name="com.droid.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="roadies.com"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: Were you able to configure this within your `config.xml` file, or were you updating `AndroidManifest.xml` directly ?

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the answers posted here worked. I tried tens of different syntaxes without any success. I was getting a parsing error while building the app via Cordova.

I finally encountered [this answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35597489/877353) which led me on the right track.

So I created a hook in the `PROJECT_ROOT/hooks/after_prepare/` folder called `010_add_intent_filters.sh`. Here is the content of this hook :

```
!/usr/bin/bash

MANIFEST=./platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml

grep -q pathPattern $MANIFEST && { print "Manifest already modified. Nothing to do."; exit 0; }

AFTER_LINE='android:name="MainActivity"'
ADDITION='\
  <intent-filter>\
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>\
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>\
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>\
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="google.com" android:pathPattern=".*"></data>\
  </intent-filter>
';

sed -i -e "/${AFTER_LINE}/a${ADDITION}" $MANIFEST
```

This finally worked. No modification to `config.xml` is required if you take the hook path. I hope this helps someone in need.

PS: I am convinced Cordova is a great technology, but I have rarely seen such a badly documented library... How painful it is to work with it is just unbelievable.