# How to launch an Ionic application and NOT open it in a web view?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm stuck at the same issue for 2 days :(

I have two `Ionic-PhoneGap` applications that need to the be able to open each other, NOT in a `WebView`, but externally (if the app is already running, it can be restarted or just continue - I will handle both).

After many hours of research, I found that, using `InAppBrowser (window.open(URL, _system))`, I was able to open externally every commercial application I tried (facebook, twitter, maps, etc). The same call, when trying to open one of my applications, opens it in a web view.

```
window.open("fb://", _system) -> opens Facebook separately.
window.open("myapp://", _system) -> opens my application in a web view.
```

I've tried to modify `AndroidManifest.xml` and the `config.xml`, but almost everything I changed is erased by the building.

For example, if I change `"android:launchMode="singleTop"` to `"android:launchMode="singleTask"` and I run "Ionic build", my change are lost..

Any solution?

Comment: Where are you testing this? In the browser or on the device?

Comment: Device, in browser "myapp://" has no meaning

Comment: @MarcoMontalto could you please post an answer instead of updating your question to add the solution? Thanks

Comment: @j0k sure, sorry! answer added

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUND!!!

Need to add those lines in app/config.xml :

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
<access origin="*" launch-external="yes" />
```

and change android:lauchMode to "Single Task" in app/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml :

...

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
<activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"  android:label="@string/activity_name" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="fkapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

...

Hope it will help someone!!

Comment: Hi Marco, can you specify which lines did you changed on the config.xml? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why the lines didn't show up, I updated the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme. The functionality you're looking for can be accomplished by URL scheme's.

Also, never directly modify a file in the /platforms/ folder. Ionic (cordova) generates these files, that's why you keep losing your changes. If you want to edit those files, you may take a look at cordova's [hooks](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html#Hooks%20Guide).

Comment: Hello and thank's for your reply.
I'm already using Custom-URL-scheme and I can open my app using this scheme, the problem is that the app is always opened in a web view, no way to make it open as an independent application.  
I'll try to learn how hooks work and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

To change the **launchMode** property add the following in `./config.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-launchMode" value="singleTask"/>
</platform>
```

Also make sure to edit `./hooks/after_prepare/030_update_platform_config.js`. There are lines:

```
var preferenceMappingData = {
    'android': {
        ...
        'android-launchMode': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: 'application/activity[@android:name=\'CordovaApp\']', destination: 'android:launchMode'},
        ...
    }
};
```

Make sure that the **parent** attribute is corresponding correctly to your activity in `./platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`. In my case I had to change `\'CordovaApp\'` to `\'MainActivity\'`.

Then you just run `ionic build android` and the property should be changed in manifest.

Comment: It might be non-obvious but the OP is talking about `update_platform_config.js` from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28217626/245966). I tried this solution and it was seemingly working randomly, turns out when I do `ionic state reset`, the hook is correctly applied after android platform restore, but then when installing plugins, *some of the plugins* is changing the value back to `singleTop`

Comment: In fact `cordova prepare` is enough to reset the value. I managed to get it finally solved with `<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />` in `config.xml`

Comment: Yes, the solution I found should be working in any case, no need to edit the js file