# App Links open HTML5/JS application

Tags: javascript, android, html, applinks

I wanted to know if, with App Links there is any possibilities to open mobile application based on HTML5/JS ?

Documentation is totally clear, and for Android it's using INTENT, but as far as I know, there is no INTENT in HTML5/JS.

Did someone already got the trick to use it ? 
Could be very usefull !

Thank you

(And by the way, great job to the App Links Team, it's a super project !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mobile application is made with cordova, phone gap build or any other solution that converts plain html/js to an Android apk, then the answer is yes, just like any other app, it is possible to specify intent filters in cordova etc as well. (see [Ionic/Cordova: Add intent-filter using config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198983/ionic-cordova-add-intent-filter-using-config-xml))

If it is just a webpage that you can open in the browser of Android, just use a normal `<a>` link.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer before. It's works as your link showed me :)
Thanks a lot !

Comment: can we pass data while opening the app?