# gets a link in sms to open specific activity

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have created a survey app which is creating dynamic Survey from android.What I want is when user create a survey and submit it by clicking button it create a link and send this link to me through sms or copy that link to my clipboard. and when I click that link it open a specific activity in my application.
I know it can happen through deep linking but I want to get the link in sms or copy it in my clipboard.I dont want to get it in Website

Answer (score 0):

you can define intent-filter for your maninifest file with your host

```
 <intent-filter>
      <data android:scheme="http" android:host="putyourdo.xyz"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I want the link in my sms not in the web

Comment: Try to put this code with your domain then after you click the url in your sms it will ask to open your app

Comment: to get the url do I have to make a Web page or site?

Comment: oh just only you want open app thought URL ?

Comment: maybe this link is help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052512/how-to-open-an-installed-app-from-an-email-url-in-android

Comment: yes.Right now I have put it like this in Manifest 

<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data android:scheme="https"  android:host="www.google.com" /> </intent-filter>
But its doing nothing when I click the link from message it open the google directly

Comment: I didn't published the app yet so I don't have any url for it