# Launching an App from a URL

Tags: android, url, android-intent, linker

I am attempting to get the Android application chooser to launch when a specific URL is clicked from within a registration e-mail. I have already looked at the below question and several others but I am still having no luck with this.

[Launching Android Application from link or email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960248/launching-android-application-from-link-or-email)

I have created my intent in the AndroidManifest.xml file as below (I've placed my website address where you see ".website.org"):

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="*.website.org"
                        android:path="/" />
                </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Is anyone able to assist me with what else I may be missing, as this is currently not launching anything and it's just loading the link directly in the default web browser?

Comment: Post your link too which you are using .

Comment: add the code how u handle intent code in main activity

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807520/6478047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. In the end I had to change my intent to the below and it had the desired result. When I click the URL specified in my intent the application chooser pops up allowing me to load the link in my app.

Just as info for anyone struggling as I did, you do not need to read data from incoming intents for the application chooser to launch, all you need is the below in your AndroidManifest file.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data   android:scheme="http" />
                    <data   android:scheme="https" />
                    <data android:host=".website.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Thanks All.

Comment: This solution is not working in android 10 / 10+

Answer (score 16):

You achieve this by **Deep linking** in your app.

First of all you need to add **intent filters** for incoming links.

> **`<action>`**
>
> Specify the ACTION_VIEW intent action so that the intent filter can be
>   reached from Google Search.
>
> **`<data>`**
>
> Add one or more  tags, each of which represents a URI format
>   that resolves to the activity. At minimum, the  tag must include
>   the android:scheme attribute.
>
> You can add more attributes to further
>   refine the type of URI that the activity accepts. For example, you
>   might have multiple activities that accept similar URIs, but which
>   differ simply based on the path name. In this case, use the
>   android:path attribute or its pathPattern or pathPrefix variants to
>   differentiate which activity the system should open for different URI
>   paths.
>
> **`<category>`**
>
> Include the BROWSABLE category. It is required in order for the intent
>   filter to be accessible from a web browser. Without it, clicking a
>   link in a browser cannot resolve to your app.
>
> Also include the DEFAULT
>   category. This allows your app to respond to implicit intents. Without
>   this, the activity can be started only if the intent specifies your
>   app component name.

I have used this url for launch my app **“http://www.example.com/gizmos”**

Look at the my **Manifest.xml** file,

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And notice that the two intent filters only differ by the **`<data>`** element.

```
<intent-filter>
  ...
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

> It might seem as though this supports only **https://www.example.com** and
>   **app://open.my.app**. However, it actually supports those two, plus
>   these: **app://www.example.com** and **https://open.my.app**.

### Read data from incoming intents

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
}
```

### Test your deep links

The general syntax for testing an intent filter URI with adb is:

```
$ adb shell am start
        -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
        -d <URI> <PACKAGE>
```

For example, the command below tries to view a target app activity that is associated with the specified URI.

```
$ adb shell am start
        -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
        -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All try to write the whole path for the Url in

```
android:host"https://www.google.com"
```

And next please check that you have not opted for default browser for link in android device.

Remove any default for link if any and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Android studio made this task very easy they introduced App Links Assistant in Android Studio 2.3 -. It does every thing for you and test as well.
It can be found in android studio

**Tools > App Links Assistant.**

useful demo video can be seen at this link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpaByLW_ctw