# I can't create a url that opens an app. Could someone help out/

Tags: url, safari

I would like to know how to make a url that opens an app on my iPhone. I should be able to go to safari and have the url open any app I want like Apple Music or YouTube. I tried looking on the internet for ways to do It but could not find anything. If someone could please answer this question, that would b great.

Comment: This question has been asked before see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887464/launching-an-app-from-a-url/47887772

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open iOS app from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883113/open-ios-app-from-browser)