# Open my google maps div with markers in native app (or fullscreen)

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, mobile

I have a website with mobile optimization (actually more like responsive optimization, but whatever).

On one page I have a Google Map with lots of custom markers. Since this map is in quite a small div (at least it appears quite small on smaller screens), it's not really friendly to use. Is there an easy way to open this exact map (with the same location AND all my custom markers) in the native iPhone/Android app? Maybe a JS-library of some sort, or even something directly developed by Google?
If this is not possible, is there maybe a trick to open it fullscreen, to at least get the native feel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but maybe you should take a look at these links

[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)
[Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228#3472228)

and try passing the longlat info within  or parameters