# How to turn GPS on in Android from browser(c#.net web application)

Tags: c#, android, browser, gps

when my sales guys access my c#.net website/web application through browser, it will send the GPSco-ordinates to the server only if the GPS tuned on, but occasionally i am facing problem when my agents turning off the gps on their android tablets, so i am thinking of turning their GPS ON grammatically , can any one please help me how can i achieve that one
Thanks

Comment: Checkout this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596860/android-intent-launch-from-browser

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread that constantly checks for a value in your webservice like `GPS status=true/false`
and call this function when the value is turned true

```
   public void turnGPSOn()
   {
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

and add Permissions in the manifest too

Comment: I don't think you understand my question/situation. I need to do it from my aspx page either by using some kind of script,

Comment: I don't think that is possible unless you have an android app that has the permission to change GPS setting in the client device