# How to launch a sip softphone call from android chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, sip

I have a rendered html page which launches calls/messages in chrome's android using different media:

1. Phone Call tel:1112341234
2. SMS        sms:1112341234?body=Hi Mr T.
3. Whatsapp   https:     //api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5491112341234&text=Hi Mr T.
4. SIP    ????

I have a GrandStream client installed, but I should use another softphone client, and I want to launch it from browser sending the number as a parameter. How should I do this? Besides, is there such thing as an Android own SIP Client?
Greetings, Marcelo.

Comment: It's described here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: And here You can get examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15596860/3706693

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<a href="sipapp:12345?body=HeyThere!">whatsapp</a>
```

More detailed about intents You can read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters)