# Trusted Web Activity: Navigating back to the native activity from redirected URL

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

I have built an application which establishes a connection with a website using Trusted Web Activity. After redirecting to the website I need to navigate back to the native activity on clicking a button placed on the website. How do I achieve this? Facing trouble as I don't have any control once redirection is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TWA is managing all link clicks for you, you can't change it. check out Deep Link and App Link resolutions ([doc in here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)) - make your native `Activity` handle some format and under web button put this specific link. TWA will try to resolve link and pass it to your native `Activity`

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="native" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>

Web:
<a href="intent:#Intent;scheme=native;end">Navigate Back</a>

Tried this. But not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: check out this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596860/android-intent-launch-from-browser), especially most voted answer. Never heard of this way of creating `Intent` from web side, but personally I would pick custom `android:scheme` way anyway (just like in accepted answer above)