# SOLVED - App links are working only when opened from outside of Android TWA application

Tags: android, applinks, trusted-web-activity, android-app-links

TLDR: app links trigger correctly from chrome, but not from inside my TWA app.

I have an Android App that opens Trusted Webview Activity launching my website.

**What I want to achieve:**
When I navigate through my website inside TWA app and click a button with URL https://example.com/app/feature I want HelloActivity to launch.

**Setup:**
I have set up app link in app manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="example.com" />
                <data android:path="/app/feature" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Problem:**
When I click the button with url https://example.com/app/feature **while in chrome browser, app link intent is triggered correctly** and my app opens with HelloActivity inflated.
However when I click the button with url https://example.com/app/feature **while inside my TWA app it does not trigger** the intent.

I have set up app links correctly but they trigger only in chrome browser not from inside the app.
I expected app links also to trigger when scrolling through the TWA application.

Comment: Solution: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15596883/6744952) helped me solve it.
To open native activity from inside TWA i have used custom schema URL on my website app://feature
And then in activity's intent filter:
<data android:scheme="app" />
<data android:host="feature" />

Comment: Post this as answer and then mark it accepted. It's fine to answer own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15596883/6744952) helped me solve it. To open native activity from the inside of TWA I have used custom schema URL on my website:
`app://feature`
And then in activity's intent filter:

```
<data android:scheme="app" /> 
<data android:host="feature" />
```