# YouTube URL Scheme

Tags: url, mobile, youtube, uri

I am trying to open youtube via a url scheme from web.

```
<a href ="youtube:h-GMDKGwE9A">test</a>
```

This doesn't launch the youtube app on Android or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

From [this pdf from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf), you should write normal urls to launch youtube on ios. Like so: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_IDENTIFIER".

For the Android part, I haven't found out more than this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709556/url-scheme-how-can-i-create-a-link-which-will-open-a-document-in-the-google-dr/17709557#17709557).