# Launch Google Drive App from another app at certain path

Tags: android, google-drive-api, launch

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to open Google Drive App at certain path? I know that Google Drive APi allow to list all files for every folder, but i prefer use Google Drive app if is possible. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this excelent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709557/1694129)

With this, you can open Google Drive native app from another app.