# Open Google Drive app on Android from Chrome browser

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to open the Google Drive app on my Android (Lollipop) phone from a webpage like this:

```
<a href="http://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folderidgoeshere" target="_blank">Drive button</a>
```

I would expect that Android presents a prompt on which I can choose to open the link in de Drive app or in Chrome. But it just opens it in Chrome and shows my Drive folder.

I tried resetting my defaults for the Drive app as wel as Chrome like this:
http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-change-default-apps-in-android
But no defaults where present which seems logical because I was never asked.

A similar link to Google Maps does behave as I want (ask to use the app):

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/adress/" target="_blank">Drive button</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Menno

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709556/url-scheme-how-can-i-create-a-link-which-will-open-a-document-in-the-google-dr

Comment: Thanks for the url Jonathan. It looks like I only have 1 option, the use of a intent url. This does open up the Drive app on my phone but it doesn't give me the choice and I have to build some sort of browser/client detection to know if I can use this intent url. Still not ideal...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by using this href:

```
<a href="doc.google.com/a/mydomain/#folders/folderid">Button</a>
```

Somehow, using "doc" in stead of "drive" in the url and pointing to a Drive folder does trigger Andriod to come up with the question if I want to use the Drive app or Chrome. A bit strange, but it does work.