# URL Scheme: Using the intent: URI scheme: Open (Launch) Google Drive App, opening a specific folder (not a file)

Tags: android, url, android-intent, hyperlink, uri

There is a great example on how to open a "Document"

[URL Scheme: How can I create a link, which will open a document in the Google Drive app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709556/url-scheme-how-can-i-create-a-link-which-will-open-a-document-in-the-google-dr)

But I am trying to "Launch" the "Drive App" on my Android Tablet, and open a specific folder...

This works for a document:

```
intent://docs.google.com/document/d/1zSzDnV-90Ke3dzCCJ2CZ6iQ3JQ3F1hL1udGDqbNwwbY/edit?usp=sharing#Intent;scheme=https;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;package=com.google.android.apps.docs;end
```

Any thoughts on launching "Drive"?  AND, Drive is opened at a specific folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
intent://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/mobile/folders/0B0BUJdH_r3v5b1pPUVFmV
```

Replace the last bit with your folder id

Comment: Thank you!  I have another one no one seems to have an answer...  if you want to take a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245700/i-am-trying-to-implement-an-html-javascript-input-type-file-id-myfile-multi