# How to communicate with android application from firefox add-on using intent?

Tags: android-intent, ipc, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to write an add-on for Firefox mobile, which can communicate with android application. Suggest alternatives to socket communication between android application and Firefox add-on.

Comment: You can do it with intent filters in the android app, but Firefox has some issues with them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966190/firefox-for-android-does-not-launch-app-when-link-is-clicked