# My app is opened when clicking on a URL in Android

Tags: android

I have defined an intent filter in order to launch my app from some kinds of URLs. The point is that it is launched for all the kinds of links, and I only want to be launched for a concrete host name. Here is my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.imin.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:logo="@drawable/img_action_icon"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTeme.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="imintheapp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/events/get/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I need to open my app ONLY in the following cases: http://imintheapp.com/events/get/xxxxxxxx where xxxxxxxx is an alphanumeric string.

What I am doing wrong?
Regards,

Comment: It looks fine.  Are you saying that from any link in any app regardless of domain, your app is an option to open the url?  So, for example, in Chrome if you click a link to www.google.com, your app will either launch or be an option presented to the user?

Comment: Yes! that's it, any url opens the app, for instance www.google.com.

Comment: I've just tested this and it works as expected, i.e. only Intent URIs of the form http://imintheapp.com/events/get/xxxxxxxx resolve to your activity. What version of Android are you working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code in Menifest.xml

```
           <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.parag-chauhan.com"
                    android:path="/test"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
```

For test create another project and run below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://www.parag-chauhan.com/test"));
startActivity(i);
```

You can also `pass parameter` in link 
for more info 
http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2013/03/make-link-in-android-browser-start-up.html

Comment: @DídacPérez it is working fine for me .Did you check call url using Intent ?

Comment: Not in my device. If I choose 'don't ask again', links like www.google.com also launch my app... it has no sense.

Comment: Hi Parag .Can you please look into this.I tried the same but nothing happens on 5.1 (Lollipop) . I want any link from browser shared into my app and I want the title of that post. Eg: gmail. I really appreciate your time and help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218607/get-your-app-when-share-is-clicked-on-chrome-url-in-android-in-5-1-lollipop . Thanks

Comment: @jason Can you plz explain little bit more?

Comment: @ParagChauhan Thanks for your response . I have added the links above to my manifest and it opens the app only if I click on any link but not when I try to share my link from chrome browser in android. I don't know why that happens . I really appreciate your help . Added new Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239039/my-app-is-not-displayed-when-i-click-on-share-on-browser-in-lollipop-5-1  Thanks.

Comment: it doesnot work even though I tried it with the files not worked

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<data
            android:host="imintheapp.com"
            android:path="/events/get/"
            android:scheme="http" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at the [intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) element of your Mainfest file. Specifically, take a look at the documentation for the [data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) sub-element.

Read those docs again.

I also suggest you to read the 2nd ans of [this Que.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)