# Launch android app when a link, on another app, is clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm trying to open my app from a link, lets say a link in gmail. The problem is that my app replaces (or it starts on top of) the gmail app instead of running stand alone. Here it's the code:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.net"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

I use replace because I don't know the technical name.

Thks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20060350/2636001 ?

Comment: It's still not working, but thanks anyway