# my app is not displayed when I click on share on browser in lollipop 5.1

Tags: android, android-sharing

I am trying to open my app when you click share on any weblink. How can I do it ? Do I need to ad any permission ? I have added the code below but I dont see my app in the share list. How can I get it to work. I really appreciate any help.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.link" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http" android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.link"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to share? Whats the mime type?

Comment: I am trying to get any http link and open it in my app. Basically when you click on share in any browser My app should show up in that list. Currently it shows gmail,hangout,trello etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add below code to an activity which you want to open while press on share

```
<intent-filter android:label="Your app Name">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

Comment: Awesome . THis works . How can I make my app on top of the share list ?

Comment: If you notice share list its alphabetically so if you want on top start name with A :)

Answer (score 0):

try using '*' wildcard char for Host field & Path Pattern fields. My Intent filter looks like:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern="/*"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*"
                android:scheme="custom" />
        </intent-filter>
```

With these changes when i click links on any chat apps or browser link, my app pops up in intent choser.

Comment: I went to google.com and I tried sharing that link from chrome browser but I did not see my app. Also where should I place the code ? I have placed it within main launcher activity .

Comment: Also should I add any permission for this ?

Comment: Yes, data tag has to be inside intent-filter under activity declaration in Manifest.  Try clicking links on other apps/browser instead of opening directly on browser tab. In my case it is - <data
                android:host="\*" android:pathPattern=".\*"
                android:scheme="customSchema" />

Comment: I tried google.com for schema but I still don't see it. Also what about permissions ?

Comment: I have created a new app to test and I have updated both manifest and gradle file on Q above. Please look into it and let me know why its not working . Thanks for your time I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share your manifest/gradle code or please look into the code above .Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer, as I mentioned it worked for me when i clicked on any links in chat messages or other apps but it didn't when I entered link address manually on browser address bar, not sure why. AFAIK you dont need any special permission for this

Comment: But trello,pushbullet,fb,gmail,hangout and many other apps are displayed here when I click on share in chrome browser ? How does that happen ?

Comment: You are right. It is partially working .How can I get it to work on chrome share ?? Please look into it.